# Convert to Specific Format Given an Int Number in C#

Tags: c#, format, decimal, converters

In this occasion my goal is to convert to a specific format given a number (int), for example:

- Convert 12345678 to 123,456.78
- Convert 1234 to 12.34
- Convert 12 to 0.12
- etcetera

Always setting a decimal part to the last two numbers of my int number and adding the "," separator respectively. I tried the following solution but it doesn't work, anyway, my solution is:

```
decimal xy = Convert.ToDecimal("20014725");
xy.ToString("##.##");
xy.ToString("C2");
xy.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
xy.ToString("##.00",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

With this code, for example:

```
xy = 123456
```

I got 123456.00 instead of 1,234.56 the number that I need.

So, which changes need my code to get my desire solution? or there is any other way to get my desire result?

As always, thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: None of those numbers have a factional value.  You'd need to divide them by 100 or 10 first.  Also how do you know that 12 should be 1.20 instead of 0.12?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I posted wrong my last example, I'm correcting it. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you just need to divide the numbers by 100 and then a format like `#,0.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var no = 12345678;
Console.WriteLine(((double)no / 100).ToString("N2"));
no = 1234;
Console.WriteLine(((double)no / 100).ToString("N2"));
no = 12;
Console.WriteLine(((double)no / 100).ToString("N2"));
```

Output:

```
123,456.78
12.34
0.12
```

Comment: Actually the OP is using `decimal` which is much better than `double` for this since some values cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point.  So `(no/100M)` would be better suited here.